# Необходимо установить ОС 10 на 20 и более компьютеров

Tags: windows-10

Вопрос такого плана устанавливал ОС с флешки и по сетки.Тут такая проблема установить ОС на 20 и более машин .Вопрос можно ли это сделать одновременно и как,чтоб не бегать от одной к другой.Желательно пошагово.Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Ну самый простой способ, это установить на один диск, подключаете остальные диски, и перекидываете на них образы, потом переименовывайте их названия в ручную.

Comment: Типа клонировать Акронисом правильно понял

Comment: Ну создаёте образ, и перекидываете его на диски, потом просто запускаете установку с уже перекинутых образов.. таким образом без флешки.

Comment: Все понял спасибо большое)